# How to restart a container instance using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, powershell-cmdlet

I was trying to setup an automated job using PowerShell to restart container instances. But seems like there no built-in PowerShell module/cmdlet to help that

I can restart a container instance using azure CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-restart)

```
az container restart --name <name> --resource-group <group>
```

Is there a way to do the same using Powershell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to give an exact answer but I think you want to make use of the [Azure Powershell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.1.0)

Comment: Are you starting a local container or one in Azure?  Are you using Docker or another containerization service?

Comment: You are right I want to make use of the Azure PowerShell module. But there is no Builtin CMDLets to restart a container. I am hoping there may be some other way to do it. As azure CLI has this feature, there should be some way. I am using azure automation environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure PowerShell not provides a commend to restart container instances directly , but we can use powershell to call Azure management APIs to restart container instances as a workaround.

1. Register an application in Azure AD ,  create an client secret for it , note its value and ID of application (you can find it in Overview) :
   [image]

[image]

2. Assign contributor role to it , so that it will has permission to manage your Azure resources : 
   [image]

3.Try the powershell script below to restart your container instances :

```
$appid = "<application ID we resistered>"
$appSecret= "<application client secret we created>"
$tenant = "<your tenant ID/NAME>"

$resourceGroup = "<resource group>"
$containerInstanceName = "<containerInstances name>"
$subscrptionId = "<subscription ID>"

$body=@{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials";
    "resource"="https://management.azure.com/";
    "client_id"=$appid;
    "client_secret"=$appSecret
}
 
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$tenant/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body 
$accessToken = $result.access_token

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscrptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/$containerInstanceName/restart?api-version=2018-10-01" -Method POST -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $accessToken"}
```

Result : 
[image]

Comment: Excellent, I was looking into the azure CLI source code, but I am not good with C#. But this helps.

Comment: This worked like charm, I was able to use same app registration which is used to create a 'Run as account' for azure automation.